# How to install SQL databases

Tags: java, sql

I have built a Java application, I have compiled it into a setup.exe, I achieved this by using "inno compiler", everything works fine. I was just wondering if there is any way to install the SQL databases automatically? I have to export it, so I was wondering if there is a way of actually doing it automatically instead of manually?

Please let me know,

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What database are you referring to? If you simply need to do something minor, then include a sqlite database with your java app and use it.  If you're using a large DB somewhere (Oracle, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc), then you can't install it with your app.

Comment: Yeah am using mySQL, so the only way to do it is manually?

Comment: You just cannot do it at all - you cannot install mysql on the computer where your app will be installed.

Comment: There most be a way, nothing is impossible in computing

Comment: Please be clear with "install the sql db"?
are you tryig to install "dtabase management system" like mysql? or you have an existing database that you want to import to your system?

Comment: Yes, I just want to install the database that I want to import to the system. The database management (phpmyadmin) is already installed, I just want to know a simple way of doing it instead of manually

Comment: Let me get this straight.  You created an application in Java and packaged it to be installed on user's computer (let's say, I am the user).  So, as part of the installation you want to install a DDBMS (mysql) on my computer?  Apart from this being a MAJOR security problem, you will fail because (1) I will not give permission to the installer to install mysql on my machine; and (2) I already have one installed that I use for my own purposes, so you would cause conflicts.

Comment: Okay please tell me what you would do then, how would you install it? what would you use and how would you do it? I am learning this is actually the first time I make a setup package.

Comment: Rewrite it as a webapp so you don't have to install mysql on every user's machine. Then you only need it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has JDBC drivers (for example https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) and creates a database that is a single file, so all you need is a directory you can write into for it to work. I would consider using it provided you do not have really large tables, as it may become a little slow. Incidentally I believe SQLite ships with PHP5, you mentioned PHP above.

I would check that there are no major licencing issues adding MySQL into something you are distributing, I expect you would at least have to amend your licence agreements. There may be some way of getting MySQL to install by using a shell script or bat file, but if MySQL is already installed then the default ports would already be used, so your MySQL would need its .ini file altering.